# Using External kv file

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I am trying to use an external kv file for my program and it is not working.  It goes up to a certain point then stops and gives me an error message. The version of Python I am using is 3.5 and the version of kivy I am using is kivy 1.9.1.

This is the code I used in the .py file:

[image: python code image]

Here is what it displays when it runs:

[image: error image]

I don't understand what going on. I am open to elaborate more on this question if it is not clear yet.

Comment: oh yah i forgot to add the kv file I used as well:

Comment: # File name: rain_coverpage(App).py
#:kivy 1.9.1
 
<Label>:
    text:  'Rain'

Answer (score 1):

In your `build` function you must return a widget. Instead you return a class of a widget (which is not a widget in itself). Replace `Label` by `Label()` which returns an instance of the class Label.

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer helped you accept it so others see your question is solved. Also [take the stackoverflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) (2 minutes) for some basic information.